# Flutter: List not updating

Tags: flutter, list, dart

I am new to Flutter. Why doesnt this list update when i try to access it from a different widget?

```
class WorkoutDay extends StatefulWidget {
  WorkoutDay({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WorkoutDay> createState() => _WorkoutDayState();

  late List<Uebung> list = _WorkoutDayState().ubungen;
```

the list is supposed to always equal the value of the ubungen list

```
class _WorkoutDayState extends State<WorkoutDay> {
  List<Uebung> ubungen = [
    Uebung(),
  ];
}
```

When i try to access list from other classes it doesnt dynamically update to the value ubungen has... what am i doing wrong?

I also tried to update the list this way:

```
setState(() {widget.list = ubungen; });
```

this should again update the list, but doesnt. (User can alter the list so i need it to be dynamic)

please help

Edit: Full code here https://github.com/JHaberlsz/stovl

Comment: Can you show your entire code including your `build` method?

Comment: because when calling `setState` , the list updated on the current class as a local state. if you want to access the value from another class which is the state value is globaly, you may use state management that control global state or App State

Comment: @pmatatias how would i do that? could you maybe provide a link?

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad i added a git link

Comment: @JHSZ ,there are some option state management. here the most easy to learn : provider https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple